# Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Laravel ,Apache y aws

Tags: php, laravel, apache, aws

necesito ayuda con el siguiente problema tengo mi aplicación subida a en ec2 de aws en Ubuntu dentro de este tiene apache , mi sistema tiene una parte donde sube imágenes en el mismo servidor.  en mi local host con apache  funciona correctamente y sube todas las imágenes pero en el servidor no sube algunas imágenes y me da como respuesta  "Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand",

probe con cambiar php.ini cambiando

```
 upload_max_filesize = 10M 
post_max_size = 20M,
 max_execution_time = 120
```

en el servidor pero no resulta y sigue dando el mismo error ,

e probado subiendo   imagenes de 5kb y funciona correctamente pero la imagen que necesito es mas o menos 600kb , no se si alguien tiene una idea de que mas puedo hacer o cambiar o si en aws se tiene que modificar algo , porfa si alguien puede ayudarme

Comment: ¿Reiniciaste el servidor Apache luego de hacer el cambio?